# Excel calculate total time from punches

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to calculate total time from same column containing date/time same row.

Use of pivot table or separate date and time into diff columns. I have the table as shown below.

[image]

First punch is at 8:48 last punch is at 19:53. I want to get the total hours between the 2 punches per day.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: !https://imgur.com/RG3EuxP this is from where i get the data for pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HOUR()` worksheet function for this:

E.g.

```
B2 = 13:07
B3 = 18:07

Formula "=HOUR(B3-B2)" yields "5".
```

Comment: The thing is that i want to do something that takes the info from the sheet in my first comment, that comes with multiple dates (even same dates, multiple punches in same day, in out) don't have a fixed number.